# gcp cloud build - cannot use SHORT_SHA substitution

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Execute `gcloud builds submit` from the local directory in my PC where the cloudbuild.yaml is located.

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:
  # Docker Build
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
    - 'build'
    - '-t'
    - 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/diabetes-prediction/diabetes-prediction-api:$SHORT_SHA'
    - '-f'
    - 'src/serving/Dockerfile'
    - '.'
```

The build fails because `SHORT_SHA` is empty causing invalid tag name ending with `diabetes-prediction-api:`.

```
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #0: invalid argument "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/default-338305/diabetes-prediction/diabetes-prediction-api:" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
```

Please advise what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the build as a trigger (from a repo) for the repo-specific values to be set.

See [Using default substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_default_substitutions)